# Microsoft Face Api verify for python

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure-cognitive-services, face-detection, image-recognition

I don't know where I put my `test1.jpg` and `test2.jpg`.

I changed this code a lot of times, but I can't...

The official api site is here : https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523a

`{"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"Request body is invalid."}}`

```py
import httplib, urllib, base64

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '',
}

params = urllib.urlencode({
})

try:
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.projectoxford.ai')
    conn.request("POST", "/face/v1.0/verify?%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `requests` library instead:

```
import requests,json

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '',
}

body = {
 "faceId":"c5c24a82-6845-4031-9d5d-978df9175426",
"peronId":"815df99c-598f-4926-930a-a734b3fd651c",
"personGroupId":"sample_group"
}

try:

   r = requests.post("https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/verify", json=body,headers=headers)
   print(r.json())
except Exception as e: # Do whatever error handling you need here.
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```